# Making an Application on eclipse(Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, layout

My issue is that i have resolved all the warning and now 4 errors are generated 2 in xml files and 2 in Main

Error No 1: (signup.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/signup">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/my_strings"   
    android:hint="@string/my_strings" 


    <requestFocus />  // Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/my_stringss" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/my_stringsss" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="@string/my_stringssss" />
```

Error No 2 (same error in search.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/search" >



   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:src="@drawable/shopping"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/historicalplacees" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/my_stringz" 
    android:hint="@string/my_stringzx" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/my_stringzz"
    android:hint="@string/my_stringzxx" 

    <requestFocus /> //Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
</EditText>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/food"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/my_stringzzz" 
    android:hint="@string/my_stringzxxx" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Error No 3 & 4( in MainActivityjava)

```
package com.example.watcharound;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// Error :R cannot be resolved to a variable
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);// Error :R cannot be resolved  to avariable
    return true;
}
```

}

Help me out please!!
i have to remove the errors by tomorrow as i have to show the interface to my supervisor on Monday and my defense of final year project is next week.
i shall be very thankful.

Comment: First and second errors: put a closing `>` before `<requestFocus />`.

Comment: Third and fourth errors: you need to import `R` class.

Comment: for third and fourth i hve written a statement as:
                                                                                                                 import  com.example.watcharound.R;                                                             in my main but it didnt work

Comment: @AndyTurner adding that > also dosent helps :(

Comment: @AndyTurner: no, not if `com.example.watcharound` is the base package of the app. The R file is generated in this package, and therefore importing is not neeeded

Comment: if i add /> before <requestFocus /> it gives the warning in </Edit Text> just below it as :This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint, and the error is still there

Answer (score 1):

No 1. You forgot to close the first EditText tag. add > before requestfocus tag.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/my_strings"   
    android:hint="@string/my_strings">
    <requestFocus />  
    </EditText>
```

No 2. Same error as No 1.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/my_stringzz"
    android:hint="@string/my_stringzxx">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

No 3 and 4 are build errors due to incorrect xml. Correct error 1 and 2 and rebuild the project.

Comment: before <requestFocus /> ??

Comment: if i add /> before <requestFocus /> it gives the warning in </Edit Text> just below it as :This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint, and the error is still there

Comment: the correct format is <EditText><requestFocus /> </EditText>. Please try with the code I added in the answer.